# Getting TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, Timestamp found what would be issue?

Tags: python, pandas

Getting following error..

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/BAB/POC/comparesheets.py", line 54, in 
sheet1['KEY_COLUMN']=sheet1[expectedsheetkeycols].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis = 1)
File "C:\2020\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6878, in apply
return op.get_result()
File "C:\2020\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 186, in get_result
return self.apply_standard()
File "C:\2020\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 296, in apply_standard
values, self.f, axis=self.axis, dummy=dummy, labels=labels
File "pandas_libs\reduction.pyx", line 618, in pandas._libs.reduction.compute_reduction
File "pandas_libs\reduction.pyx", line 128, in pandas._libs.reduction.Reducer.get_result
File "C:/BAB/POC/comparesheets.py", line 54, in 
sheet1['KEY_COLUMN']=sheet1[expectedsheetkeycols].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis = 1)
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, Timestamp found

Code …

```
sheet1['KEY_COLUMN']=sheet1[expectedsheetkeycols].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis = 1)
```

how would I change above line to avoid the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want avoid join all `datetimes` columns add [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
sheet1['KEY_COLUMN']=sheet1[expectedsheetkeycols].select_dtypes(object).apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis = 1)
```

If want also `datetimes` columns convert all columns to strings by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
sheet1['KEY_COLUMN']=sheet1[expectedsheetkeycols].astype(str).apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis = 1)
```

EDIT:

```
expectedsheetkeycols = ['Date','a','b']
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=5)
sheet1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'a': list('abcde'),'b': list('fghij')})  
print (sheet1)
        Date  a  b
0 2017-04-03  a  f
1 2017-04-04  b  g
2 2017-04-05  c  h
3 2017-04-06  d  i
4 2017-04-07  e  j

sheet1['KEY_COLUMN1']=sheet1[expectedsheetkeycols].select_dtypes(object).apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis = 1)
sheet1['KEY_COLUMN2']=sheet1[expectedsheetkeycols].astype(str).apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis = 1)
print (sheet1)
        Date  a  b KEY_COLUMN1   KEY_COLUMN2
0 2017-04-03  a  f          af  2017-04-03af
1 2017-04-04  b  g          bg  2017-04-04bg
2 2017-04-05  c  h          ch  2017-04-05ch
3 2017-04-06  d  i          di  2017-04-06di
4 2017-04-07  e  j          ej  2017-04-07ej
```

Comment: thanks for the message..for the options getting following error

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: @KumarPrvn - Tested and for me working nice, it seems some data related issue (or problem of another code)